# How to check where does pkg_check_modules find a module?

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, cmake-modules

I'm new to `CMAKE` and now I'm trying to build a `C++` library and faced some problem.

I'm trying to understand how does `PKG_CHECK_MODULES (3RD_PARTY_LIB REQUIRED stream)` work. I read the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html) and it is said:

> When the ‘REQUIRED’ argument was set, macros will fail with an error
>   when module(s) could not be found

The thing is there should be no `stream` module installed, but the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` does not fail. I added the following

```
MESSAGE("\n3RD_PARTY_LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${3RD_PARTY_LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}\n")
```

and it prints the following

```
3RD_PARTY_LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS = /home/rjtor/work/libsrv/3rdp/stream/include
```

But the directory `/home/rjtor/work/libsrv/3rdp/stream/include` does not really exist.

Is there a way to check why is the module `stream` in the example found? How to check where is it located?

Comment: How is this variable populated? The `REQUIRED` checks that the variable is set to a specific `NOTFOUND` value. If it's manually set to something, then it gets validated.

Comment: Like `find_package`, the function `pkg_check_modules` sets `XXX_FOUND` variable which reflects whether the package has been found or not. Note, that `pkg_check_modules` just read corresponded `.pc` file. Whether the file is wrong or not, you should check by other means.

Comment: @Tsyvarev As far as I understood the `.pc` files contain meta-information needed to use the given library like compiler/linker flags, minimum required version etc... But the actual module need to be installed by itself. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, in a correct environment, `.pc` file is installed alongside with the actual module. But it could be that  your environment is not so correct - e.g., you have removed the actual module, but `.pc` file remains. Have you tried to clear CMake cache (remove `CMakeCache.txt` file)? It could contain data from the first configuration, but that data could be obsolete.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Actually you were right. The environment was not correctly installed.